# Two topmost windows. Which shows?

Tags: windows

If you have two desktop windows on Windows that both have the property of `TopMost` or `AlwaysOnTop` set to true, and said windows overlap, how does Windows decide which window to display on top?

Comment: I'd say it would use the same logic as with windows that aren't on top. (I check it out in Linux, and that is what happened)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows displays on top the window which is higher up the z-order.

Comment: Thanks! here's a good reference I googled on z-order! http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545(v=vs.85).aspx